# using timer objects dynamically c#/.net

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer, thread-safety

I wanted to see if anyone had any experience or tips on using timers dynamically.  We need a windows service that will periodically check a text file.  The text file will hold a market name and a start time.   The service then needs to create a timer to perform a countdown and write out countdown information to an xml file... like 23minutes

all of that works now on a windows app for one timer and one countdown...we now want to make this dynamic...

so when the service starts, it would create a timer for each market/countdown time... (exp Phoenix 10am, Chicago 11:45pm, etc).

Then the service would check that text file for any NEW entries...  So if the file had Phoenix, Chicago and then had New York added, we would want the service to keep the Phoenix and Chicago timers running and then start a timer for New York.

im just not sure how multiple timers running under a service would interact and how the threading will work when they all need to write to the same xml file.

any thoughts on this?

Comment: You're going to have to synchronize on your file writing operations - TextWriters, BinaryWriters etc are all not thread safe.

Comment: Also, if could be helpful to clarify a point; when you say you inspect an XML file, you are saying: Load data from XML File A, wait some specified period of time, and then write to XML File B right?

Comment: @VulcanCCIT: Can you edit your question to elaborate on Tejs' questions?  I couldn't give you a solid answer because I can't understand how *exactly* your system is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> im just not sure how multiple timers running under a service would interact and how the threading will work when they all need to write to the same xml file.
>
> any thoughts on this?

It won't work well.

Timers are queued to the thread pool.  The thread pool will only create a certain number of active threads at a time:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx

> The number of operations that can be queued to the thread pool is limited only by available memory; however, the thread pool limits the number of threads that can be active in the process simultaneously

In addition, writing to the same file from multiple threads is going to give you bad results.

Not to mention it will be much harder to figure out what your application is doing if you have all those threads running.

**A simpler approach**

Take an existing timer and build your own timing system upon it that doesn't use threads.

- Create a structure defining a countdown entry.

Code:

```
public class Countdown
{
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public event Action Elapsed { get; set; }

    public void RaiseElasped()
    {
        if(Elapsed != null)
            Elapsed();
    }
}
```

- Read your file, and create: `Dictionary<string, Countdown>` (name -> countdown).  Put the same code in each action that you were going to put in the timers.
- Create a `FileSystemWatcher` to look for changes to your input file.  When the file is triggered, modify the dictionary as necessary.
- Create a single timer with a resolution of one minute.
- Every time that timer is triggered, check each item in the dictionary.  If the target time has passed, call `RaiseElapsed`.  (possibly remove it from the dictionary, too?)

From this point, it is hard to determine exactly what you'd want to do, because you didn't describe what gets written to a file, when it happens, how often, or what happens once your countdown has elapsed.  You should be able to figure out the rest yourself, though.

The advantage of this approach is that single-threaded programs are much easier to debug, and you won't get any of the issues your question asked about (concurrent file access, or having too many threads running).

The disadvantage is that it might bog down when you have a lot of entries.  But if you have a lot of entries, you should really be using a database instead of of files.

Comment: I think this would work well.  on the forms app, I am writing the elapsed time (days, mins, secs until countdown deadline)for each timezone...on each 1 second tick of the timer..  At the end of the countdown, the timer just stops..  so yes, probably would pull it out of the dictionary... ill try it out..and I like the idea of FileSystemWatcher as well.  SO looks like I need 1 timer, and just calculate different "elapsed" times depending on the dictionary and write the output out to different files...one per dictionary entry...

Comment: @VulcanCCIT: Sounds like this will work, but I'd like to provide additional feedback on the overall design.  What type of times come in as input - total time to count down, or a target time to count down until?  What type of times will be output in each of the output files?  Remaining time?  What consumes that output file - the countdown app itself?  The reason I ask is that some of these pieces might not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain `Dictionary<string,DateTime>` that holds market name and times. At regular interval (say every minute?) you can scan through the dictionary and calculate elapsed time by simply using DateTime.Subtract() and write the result to your output file. You might also want to look at [Stopwatch class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx%20Stopwatch%20class).

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of the dictionary as well.  I have the timer code all written, but I was concerned with multiple timers all writing to the same xml file...

Comment: actually, it would be seperate xml files... each timer would write to its own file directory...so that should be ok thread wise....  so I guess my only remaining concern would be multiple timers in the service (stopwatch class looks good!!)

Comment: @VulcanCCIT: Just make one timer (like ShitalShah said).  Have that timer trigger the countdown processing on all the items in the dictionary.  Then you don't need to worry about concurrency issues.  Unless you have a *huge* amount of data, then the fact that you aren't processing them in parallel isn't a big deal.  If you have a huge amount of data, you need to use a database, not a simple file.

Comment: @merlyn  well the need for multiple timers is that the countdown periods might differ...  Chicago may need to coundtown time from midnight on July 1... New York might need to countdown time until New years, ...each timer would be a seperate stopwatch so to speak.

Comment: @VulcanCCIT: You basically build your own timers on top of a single "`Timer`".  I added my own answer that elaborates on what I'm talking about.